# Add the ability to view upvotes and downvotes count in android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

When viewing questions in android app, I've tried to see how many upvotes and downvotes the question has. Normally it is done by clicking on the score, but it didn't work in app. I have the privilege on the site.

Is that option hidden somewhere or simply not implemented?

Comment: This feature's not implemented in the android app yet, but it should be! I changed your tag to [feature-request]